# US visa renewal via DropBox

Tags: usa, international-travel, b1-b2-visas, us-visa-waiver-program, nigeria

I'm applying from Nigeria to renew my visa for Dropbox (I have met all the requirements) and I answered questions regarding DHL drop-off, but the last question I answered states the following:

> Schedule Consular Appointment - Applicants for U.S. visas are required to appear in person for a visa interview at the U.S. Embassy/Consulate. Please schedule an appointment for the interview".

What does this mean? I'm really scared because I already clicked submit, and I know the interview waiting times are long.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you checked all the questions correctly? Eligibility for interview waiver does not guarantee that the interview will be waived https://www.ustraveldocs.com/bd/Drop%20box%20checklist-15thMay'15.pdf

Comment: @Traveller yes. I was told “based onyour responses to the questions it appears that you qualify to submit your documents at the DHL document delivery location in Abuja ONLY on the day and time of your appointment.  Do you wish to submit and not apply in person at the U.S. Embassy or U.S. Consulate Nigeria?

Comment: @Traveller does this mean I have to do an in person interview?

Comment: Where are you applying *from*? Consular officers may still require an in-person interview on a case-by-case basis, taking into account local conditions.

Comment: @Traveller I am applying from Nigeria. Does this mean I don’t qualify for the interview waiver and I have to go for an in-person interview? Plus What would they send me in the mail I’m expecting?

Comment: Based on info in the linked pdf in my first comment, you should get a Drop box confirmation letter. From what you’re saying I suspect you will have to go for an in-person interview but I have not personally used the process so I’m not sure. Hopefully someone with better knowledge will see your question and  provide a reliable answer

Comment: Were you able to get your visa renewed? How long was the processing time?